# Is the hashmap traversal order certain，I'm not talking about order, I'm talking about stability

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

There are two hashmaps. Put and remove them for any number of times in the same order. Finally, foreach the hashmap. Are the output results of the two hashmaps consistent？

I think it should be consistent, but I can't find any data to clearly prove it

Comment: There's no guarantee about the iteration order of `HashMap` at all. That means you can't depend on two HashMaps that took the exact same operations on the same objects in the same JVM instance to produce the same iteration order. As a matter of implementation, I think that this *can* (and probably will) happen, but since it's not part of the spec that fact can easily change with the next JVM release. If you need *any guarantee* at all about traversal order then use something like `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: This is not answerable without a clear specification for "put and remove them for any number of times in the same order"

Comment: It might be interesting for you that a randomization did already exist in an earlier version. As [JDK-8006593](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8006593) indicates, it has been removed due to performance considerations, not because it was contradicting the specification. So, randomization may come back at any time, if the implementors have a reason.

Comment: @Holger
This is really a little relevant，but what the early randomization affected？

Comment: @Stephen C
sorry for my weak English.
For example, insert and delete the same key-value pairs from two maps in the same order, and finally traverse the two maps

Comment: What are the exact types of the keys?

Comment: @wjc - Look at the Java 7u source repo mirror on Github and track exactly what changes were made to the `HashMap` source code in 7u40.  That is when the issue tracker says that the randomization was removed.

Comment: @StephenC
Does the type of key affect this? Take String and Integer for example

Comment: Well yes ... but take an object which has an identity hashcode for a counter example.  In that case the ordering will depend on the *actual* identity hashcodes  ... and we need a clear understanding of what the OP *actually* means by "the same".  But either way, the *precedent* of the randomization feature noted by Holger means that the answer to the OPs question is Java version specific ... and you can't rely on it not changing ... again.

Comment: There is no *guarantee* but results are often repeatable. They're repeatable often enough that people inadvertently depend on the ordering, as if it were guaranteed, until a change in ordering causes a bug. For example, HashMaps of different initial capacities might result in differing iteration orders even when the same mappings are added in the same order.

Comment: Randomization of iteration order is useful for preventing code from inadvertently depending on the iteration order. The maps produced by `Map.of` and `Map.copyOf` have randomized iteration order. We probably won't add randomization of HashMap itself because it would probably break too much code.